# NodeJS Returning data to client browser

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, powershell, timer

I think we need some help here. Thanks in advance.

I have been doing programming in .Net for desktop applications and have used Timer objects to wait for a task to complete before the task result are shown in a data grid. Recently, we switched over to NodeJs and find it pretty interesting. We could design a small application that executes some tasks using PowerShell scripts and return the data to the client browser. However, I would have to execute a Timer on the client browser (when someone clicks on a button) to see if the file, that Timer receives from the server, has "ENDOFDATA" or not. Once the Timer sees ENDOFDATA it triggers another function to populate DIV with the data that was received from the server.

Is this the right way to get the data from a server? We really don't want to block EventLoop. We run PowerShell scripts on NodeJS to collect users from Active Directory and then send the data back to the client browser. The PowerShell scripts are executed as a Job so EventLoop is not blocked.

Here is an example of the code at NodeJs:

In the below code can we insert something that won't block the EventLoop but still respond to the server once the task is completed? As you can see in the code below, we would like to send the ADUsers.CSV file to the client browser once GetUsers.PS1 has finished executing. Since GetUSers.PS1 takes about five minutes to complete the Event Loop is blocked and the Server can no longer accept any other requests.

```
app.post("/LoadDomUsers", (request, response) => {
//we check if the request is an AJAX one and if accepts JSON
if (request.xhr || request.accepts("json, html") === "json") {

    var ThisAD = request.body.ThisAD
    console.log(ThisAD);

    ps.addCommand("./public/ps/GetUsers.PS1", [{
        name: 'AllParaNow',
        value: ScriptPara
    }])
    ps.addCommand(`$rc = gc ` + __dirname + "/public/TestData/AD/ADUsers.CSV");
    ps.addCommand(`$rc`);
    ps.invoke().then((output) => {
         response.send({ message: output });
         console.log(output);
    });
}
```

});

Thank you.

Comment: But it should not be blocking the event loop, since you use `.then()`. It is not synchronous. What makes you think it is?

Comment: I know it's not, but my question is can we insert something in above code so it doesn't block the Event Loop and still send the response to client with data? May be a timer? but I'm afraid I'm running out of ideas at the moment.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure to understand. You can always set a timeout, like, "after 30 seconds, reply to the client". But reply with what? Since `GetUsers.PS1` won't be finished yet? Besides, you can only reply once.

Comment: You say `I know it's not` [synchronous], but you say exactly the opposite in your question : `Since GetUSers.PS1 takes about five minutes to complete the Event Loop is blocked`. So is it or is it not blocked? :) My guess is, it's not (because you use `then()`).

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. My only concern here is do you really implement a timer for each button at client side? Lets say I have 100 buttons on a web and it might take atleast five minutes for each task associated with the button to finish the return the data to the client. Say I click Button1, Button2 and so on and then associated timers run at client side to wait for the data.

Comment: OR what I was thinking of inserting something in above code as a wrapper that do not block the Event Loop. Can we insert a timer in above code then the PowerShell script will run under the timer and not block the event loop.

Comment: Oooh I get it, you want something that sends like seconds to the client? Are you trying to make your server send 1... 2... 3... every second to the client, so the browser knows that the server is working? If that's what I think, you need [websockets](https://socket.io/) for that. It's the only way for the server to push data to the client. Then, when the work is done, simply send it back with `response.send()` as you currently do.

Comment: Humm...websockets - never heard of that but I can try. Is there any example you would like to provide including a websocket in above code or it's a totally different thing? Thank you

Comment: It's a totally different thing. Websockets are like a pipe, or a telephone, between client and server. You can send data from one to another, it's bidirectional. That's what they use for chats (Whatsapp etc). It's the only way I know a server can spontaneously push data to a client, otherwise it can only respond. Websockets don't expect a response, they just push stuff through the pipe. You can add socket.io to your current app and create a two-way "communication pipe".

Comment: Sure. I thought we could insert a timer right after poweshell script runs. Note that poweshell script runs in background so it’s not blocking event loop. Timer runs every 20 seconds to monitor a file generated by the poweshell script and look for ENDOFDATA in the file. Once it sees ENDOFDATA the timer stops and sends the  response to client. what do you think? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe your problem isn't that clear. I had to read some of the comments in your initial question just to be sure I understood the issue. Honestly, you could just utilize various CSV NPM packages to read and write from your active directory with NodeJS.

I/O is non-blocking with NodeJS, so you're not actually blocking the EventLoop. You can handle multiple I/O requests, since NodeJS will just create threads for each one,
and continue execution on the main thread until the I/O operations complete and send back the data to its function reference, adding them as functions to the callstack and resuming program execution from those function's references. After you get the I/O data, you just send it back to the client through the response object. There should be no timers needed.

So is the issue once the powershell script runs, you have to wait for that initial script to complete before being able to handle pending requests? I'm still a bit unclear...